# How to set non standard serial port speed

Tags: serial, uart

I need to set the serial port /dev/ttyS0 to 250k bit/sec in order to send commands to another device expecting 250k.
I am using Python and trying to set the speed with the command

ser=serial.Serial(
   port='/dev/ttyS0',
   baudrate=250000,
   parity  ....and so on

This generates an error because the port speed is a non standard unix speed the nearest being 230400   ....which is not close enough.

Note this is not USB. The Rasberry Pi B has the ability to go to this speeds and I have confirmed to myself that it gets to the higher speed ranges with and oscilloscope.

Looks like I need to recompile the kernel. I can do that, but can someone help with which code needs to be modified to get a new non standard uart speed.

Comment: There are many ways of doing it. For a C answer, mostly translatable to python, see [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19440268/1329652).

Answer (score 3):

The clock speed of the serial port is `3000000Hz` (3MHz).

We can UNDERclock this (as low as 1MHz), but we **cannot** OVERclock it (with any confidence).

So we will pick the Baud Rate one-above the speed you want, and slow it down...

The next speed up from `250000` is `460800`

Now a bit of maths:

```
(NormalClockSpeed / NormalBaud) * DesiredBaud => NewClockSpeed
...where NormalBaud > DesiredBaud

(3000000 / 460800) * 250000 = 1627604
```

Quick maths sanity-check: 250,000 is a bit more than half of 460,800 ...and 1,627,604 is a bit more than half of 3,000,000 ...yep that looks right :)

So if we reduce the serial clock speed to 1627604 and then specify a serial port speed of 460800, the upshot will be a serial port that runs at 250000.

You can even do the maths backwards to double check things:

```
(NewClockSpeed * NormalBaud) / NormalClockSpeed => ResultantBaud
(1627604 * 460800) / 3000000 = 249,999.97
```

249,999.97 is uncommonly accurate, you can get away with a lot more deviation than that! [citation required]

So we edit `/boot/config.txt`; Set the serial clock speed to 1627604; And the Baud Rate to 460800

```
init_uart_clock=1627604
init_uart_baud=460800
```

Bingo. /dev/ttyS0 is running at 250KBaud

Answer (score 0):

Linux kernel drivers should be organized by type in the kernel source. Look for the driver that your pi uses, and then inspect the code.

Long ago, I had a quad-port serial card, and supporting it just required adjusting the IRQ value in a driver for a very similar card.

Looking through `linux/drivers/tty`, I see `tty_ioctl.c` which has a table of baud rates near line 269. I haven't tried modifying `baud_table`, but this is where I would start.

```
/*
 * Routine which returns the baud rate of the tty
 *
 * Note that the baud_table needs to be kept in sync with the
 * include/asm/termbits.h file.
 */
static const speed_t baud_table[] = {
        0, 50, 75, 110, 134, 150, 200, 300, 600, 1200, 1800, 2400, 4800,
        9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200, 230400, 460800,
#ifdef __sparc__
        76800, 153600, 307200, 614400, 921600
#else
        500000, 576000, 921600, 1000000, 1152000, 1500000, 2000000,
        2500000, 3000000, 3500000, 4000000
#endif
};
```

Comment: I downloaded the Rasbery source. In linux/drivers/tty there are C files starting with tty_ and a directory called serial with many files that may be relevant. i was hoping to get a run down on what I might need to change

Comment: The code you cite doesn't mean much. For a full scoop on how to set baudrates on linux, see [this q/a](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19440268/1329652).

Comment: @KubaOber - please move your comment into a standalone answer so that others can more easily find and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

On a Pi3 running Raspbian Jessie (it's still on the 4.1 kernel because Adafruit has not bothered to upgrade their PiTFT+ drivers to 4.4).

```
pi@rp3:~ $ uname -r
4.1.14-v7+

pi@rp3:~ $ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  8 2015, 00:52:26)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from serial import Serial
>>> Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=250000)
Serial<id=0x76aba8d0, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=250000, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
```

It also works on an RPi2 with a 4.4 kernel.

What error are you getting?

Comment: Odd? I have a second PI here at work and tried the command again and it worked. Maybe different kernels?  Nevertheless it still doesn't work. normally if you do the Serial(port=/dev/ttyS0,baudrate=9600, the baud rate appears using command line stty -a -F /dev/ttyS0  If I check serial output with an oscilloscope the signal is flat but is good using a standard baud rate